# How to get the SVG root element in Snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

In Raphael it is easy to get the SVG root element:

```
svg_item = Raphael(0, 0, 3000, 3000);
svg_item.canvas.id = "main_svg";
svg_item.canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

but how this can be done in Snap.svg? The following doesn't work:

```
svg_item = Snap(3000, 3000);
svg_item.canvas.id = "main_svg";
svg_item.canvas.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
svg_item = Snap(3000, 3000);
svg_item.root.node.id = "main_svg";
svg_item.root.node.style.pointerEvents = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try paper rather than canvas, so..

```
svg_item.paper.id = "main_svg";
svg_item.paper.attr({ style: "pointer-events: none" });
```